# How To Use REINDEX in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm testing `REINDEX` operation of QuestDB in the localhost:9000 Web Console.

But there continuously comes error:

`[23:12:14] Cannot lock table: /usr/local/var/questdb/db/my_table`

Here is my code:

```c
drop TABLE if EXISTS 'my_table';

CREATE TABLE my_table
  (symb SYMBOL CAPACITY 128 NOCACHE, price DOUBLE, ts TIMESTAMP)
timestamp(ts);

ALTER TABLE 'my_table' ALTER COLUMN symb ADD INDEX;

REINDEX TABLE 'my_table' COLUMN symb LOCK EXCLUSIVE;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

According to ([REINDEX command documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/reindex/)), operation can only be performed when there is no other reader and writer working on the table.
Querying or modifying table creates readers and writers that are cached for some time (depending on settings such as cairo.inactive.reader.ttl, cairo.inactive.writer.ttl, etc. ).
Lock should be released if you wait ~ 5 minutes or restart QuestDB instance .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested it and found that I have to restart the service to release the lock. Are there any ways to acquire/release the lock manually so that I don't have to restart the instance every time I want to reindex?

Comment: There's no explicit command for that unfortunately . Feel free to submit an issue or  feature request at https://github.com/questdb/questdb .